# Python logging command does not work at real time

Tags: python, logging, tkinter

I have a logging widget in Tkinter ( ScrolledText ) with a `TextHandler` class that handle logs and print theme in widget

```
class TextHandler(logging.Handler):

    def __init__(self, text):
        # run the regular Handler __init__
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        # Store a reference to the Text it will log to
        self.text = text

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)

        def append():
            self.text.configure(state='normal')
            self.text.insert(Tkinter.END, msg + '\n')
            self.text.configure(state='disabled')
            # Autoscroll to the bottom
            self.text.yview(Tkinter.END)

        self.text.after(0, append)


st = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(self, width=190, height=9, state='disabled')
st.configure(font='TkFixedFont')
st.place(x=0, y=539)

text_handler = TextHandler(st)

# Logging configuration
logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log',
                            level=logging.INFO,
                            format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Add the handler to logger
self.logger = logging.getLogger()

self.logger.addHandler(text_handler)
```

And call `logging.info(msg)` for log messages. but there is a problem. everything is work well but when this function called before a process ( for example some works with lists ) my logs appear after that !!

```
logging.info("message")
print "message"
for topic in news:
    ...
```

`print` method works fine here but there is problem for `logging`. i have my log message just **after the loop end**.
So ... what is the problem ?

Comment: I don't know if this is the real reason since I haven't run into that in Python, but in Java I found that things aren't written to the file until I close the file. Python closes everything after the script stops, so maybe something similar is happening with the timing.

Comment: Thank you. everything work fine in normal situation. i have this problem when i have a process loop after log command @DavyM

Comment: You don't have to close the file, flushing is enough. I.e. file.flush()

Comment: There is not any file problem ... it is something else @R2RT

Comment: Ye, my mistake, but I still think that `flushing` is keyword here. You need to synchronize inputs that go around your program.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `after(0, ...)`. I'm not sure if it's the only problem, but it's definitely one problem. You are starving the event handler -- the "idle" queue will never empty, so it doesn't have the chance to service normal events. You have, in effect, created an infinite loop.

You should give a small non-zero interval, which will help this problem.